# How do I provide my own insert link dialog in pagedown editor?

Tags: javascript, pagedown

I use pagedown for markdown editing and already used the `insertImageDialog` for overriding the default dialog for inserting images. Now I want to do the same for insert a link. I found the `plainLinkText` hook, but it does not seem to do, what I want, since it is only for post processing the url. How can I provide my own dialog for inserting a link?

Comment: I'm interested in this too. Did you find an answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter, '', options);
editor.hooks.set("insertImageDialog", function (callback) {
    //show your dialog
    //example:
    //showPrompt({
    //    message: 'Input an url',
    //    onOK: function(url){ callback(url); }
    //});
    return true;
});
```